# View Pager in Fragment

Tags: android

Once again, I am so annoyed by the AndroidSDK . Why does this have to be so complicated?

---

I have a ViewPager that I want to populate with my Fragment. I implemented this on an Activity and it works. But when its in another Fragment the whole thing crashes and the erros messages tells me nothing:

```
07-01 12:58:20.210: E/AndroidRuntime(10146): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tabwrapper, container);

    List<Fragment> fragments = getFragments();
    pageAdapter = new MyPageAdapter(getActivity()
            .getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);



    pager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.viewpager); 
    pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter); // <- CRASH!

    return v;
}
```

BTW: The whole thing is based on this tutorial: http://architects.dzone.com/articles/android-tutorial-using

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs beacuse you have to remove all views before set adapter in view pager so get right way..... So check this:

```
   MyPageAdapter pageAdapter ;

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tabwrapper, container);

    List<Fragment> fragments = getFragments();
    pageAdapter = new MyPageAdapter(getActivity()
        .getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);



    pager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.viewpager); 
    pager.removeallviews();

    pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter); // <- CRASH!

    return v;
```

}

Comment: Yes. Its still the message about one "specific child" already having a parent.

Comment: I think the problem is occurring because of List of fragment so i think you should remove the current fragment from previous fragment so you can something right.

Comment: You're right. If the fragment list is empty the app doesn't crash. The message is the same which confused me ... sorry, I don't understand the last part of you message. Get what right?

Comment: My mean to say according to your question that first time in first view it can't get error but whenever pass to new fragment its crashed....

Comment: Thats right. But the fragment currently inflates a empty layout with one dummy UI element. I doubt that I did a mistake there. Also, all of this worked when it was an Activity.

Comment: So what is the procedure when you have pass to fragment from activity??

Comment: Sorry I don't know what you mean. What procedure? passing what? all I want to do is have a fragment that holds a bunch of other fragments.  These should be swipeable (hence viewpager) and later also have tabs (within the fragment). At this point, I'm not passing anything anywhere. For now I just have dummy fragments to get the hang of this unbelievably complicated way to achieve a rather simple UI design

Comment: 1) http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/13/android-tabs-    viewpager-swipe-able-tabs-ftw/                                        2) http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.co.il/2012/10/viewpager-example-in-android.html                                               3)http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/05/android-page-swiping-using-viewpager/                                               Check this links this will help you.

Comment: I know these resources (except the Tech Training one). The viewpager is not the problem. I got everything to work just fine. Also the thing with tabs. The problem is that I cannot get this working within a fragment. Still, thanks a lot for trying to helpwith your pretty fast answers!

Answer (score 0):

you should not use the `ViewGroup` that `onCreateView` provides as container to put your inflated view:

Change

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tabwrapper, container);
```

to

`View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tabwrapper, null)`;

Answer (score 0):

This might shed a little light on the topic: http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments

IMHO: I don't understand why developers put up with these tools. I find them impossible to work with. No wonder there are so many low-quality apps on the Play store. I'm looking forward to the day this project is done. Won't be working with this OS anytime soon again ...